# PowerShell string concatenation gives newlines

Tags: string, powershell, jar, newline

#### **Note**: The actual error from Java/Closure Compiler came from the missing `t` in **--js-ou*t*putfile**!

I have this PowerShell script:

```
cls
$jsFiles = @();

Get-ChildItem | Where {$_.PsIsContainer} | Foreach {
    $dir = $_.FullName;
    $jsFile = $dir + "\" + $_.Name + ".js";
    if (Test-Path ($jsFile)) {
        $jsFiles += $jsFile;
    }
}

$wd = [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory();

# Build Closure Compiler command line call
$cmd = @("-jar $wd\..\ClosureCompiler\compiler.jar");

Foreach ($file in $jsFiles) {
    # Both insert a newline!

    $cmd += "--js $file";
    #$cmd = "$cmd --js $file";
}


$cmd = "$cmd --js_ouput_file $wd\all.js";

Invoke-Expression "java.exe $cmd"
```

The problem is that newlines are inserted on each `+=` or `$cmd = "$cmd str"` call!

Echoargs gives me this output:

```
Arg 0 is <-jar>
Arg 1 is <S:\ome\Path\compiler.jar>
Arg 2 is <--js>
Arg 3 is <S:\ome\Path\script1.js>
Arg 4 is <--js>
Arg 5 is <S:\ome\Path\script2.js>
...
Arg 98 is <--js_ouput_file>
Arg 99 is <S:\ome\Path\all.js>
```

(Possibly) therefore, I get some errors from `java.exe`:

```
java.exe : "--js_ouput_file" is not a valid option
At line:1 char:1
+ java.exe -jar ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ("--js_ouput_file" is not a valid option:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rewrite to much simple version:

```
cls

$wd = [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory();

# Build Closure Compiler command line call
$cmd = "-jar $wd\..\ClosureCompiler\compiler.jar";

$arrayOfJs = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include "*.js" | % { "--js $_.FullName" };

$cmd += [string]::Join(" ", $arrayOfJs);

Invoke-Expression "java $cmd --js_ouput_file $wd\all.js"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and for code reduction!). But I'm still getting the erorr. Please see my question (forogot to include the error messages at first).

Comment: I've just tested it with Echoargs, but there are still the same newlines.

Comment: The same error :( But as manojlds mentioned, I don't have (want) to use $cmd as an array. I just misunderstood the array operator somewhere...

Comment: I have update script, and `$cmd` is not an array. Join array operation is using `$arrayOfJs`

Comment: Thanks for your help but the newlines are still there.

Comment: I have add output of $cmd type, could you try it now. Should be `System.Object`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15799/discussion-between-akim-and-comfreek)

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
$cmd = @(...);
```

you are creating an array and hence the subsequent `+=` on it is appending elements to the array and is not string concatenation. Just have it as a string, or before using $cmd. Do something like:

```
$cmd -join " "
```

Which will join together the elements into a single space-separated string. By default when the array is coerced into a string, you will see new lines between the elements.

Comment: Okay, I've changed it to `$cmd = " -jar..."`. But I'm still getting all the newlines!

Comment: None of your answers had the solution (it was the missing *t* in `--js-ouputfie`), but akim has also shortened my code. I thank you both!